# Android Fragment with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, fragment, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

Here's a Activity with a ViewPager as ContentView and the adapter has 4 fragments one of them (position 2)has a CoordinatorLayout as a RootView.

The first time I switch to the fragment , each view behaves normally, but when i switch to the last fragment(position 4, fragment of position 2's view has been destroyed.

I have used ButterKnife to unbind the view), then switch back to fragment of position 2, the CoordinateLayout seemed to add a paddingTop automatically.

The layouts of activity and fragment are mentioned below

Activity layout.xml

```
<com.conjugate.fudai.views.StillViewPager
    android:id="@+id/main_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


<include layout="@layout/layout_main_navigation_bar" />
```

Fragment layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <com.conjugate.fudai.views.adbanner.AdBanner
                android:id="@+id/banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/main_home_banner_height" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/main_home_notify_height"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/main_home_notify_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_home_notify_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/trumpet" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/notify"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_height"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_bar_menu"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/search_bar_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/search_bar_menu" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_bar_search_bg"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/search_search_icon_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/search_search_icon_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/search_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="6dp"
                        android:text="@string/search_hint"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_bar_msg"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/search_bar_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/search_bar_msg" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

[image]

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Try using `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);`

Comment: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4) may cause OOM, my fragments has so many pictures.